# Executing two contracts on one button click

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

I tried executing two contract when I press a button. Everything seems alright until the transaction page appears and I have 3 contract transactions, the first contract executed once and the second contract executed twice. I tried cancelling the duplicated transaction but it will tell me that the one I submitted has failed.

The only way for it to work is to let the first and second contract be confirmed then submit the duplicated one. But the outcome is that I submitted two transactions of the second contract. I attached a photo below for reference.

I'm quite new to solidity and also the web3. I don't really know where i'm doing it wrong. Please help

[This](https://codeshare.io/5D7KeO) is my full source code, the problem only starts at line 158 - 203

[image: This is when I click the button]

Comment: Without the contracts source code my guess is it might be that you have to execute `fund()` and when it is confirmed execute `InvestProject()`. To do that in javascript you need to execute `InvestProject()` inside the callback for `fund()`.